# expo and react native-cli giving me this same error every time I run any react native application

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-cli

```
Cannot find module **'C:\Users\user\Desktop\ReactNative\InventorsArena\node_modules\@babel\traverse\node_modules\debug\src\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry**
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\ReactNative\InventorsArena\node_modules\@babel\traverse\node_modules\debug\src\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:320:19)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:533:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:875:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\ReactNative\InventorsArena\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\index.js:10:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
```

`
expo and react native-cli giving me this same error every time I run any react native application.
Here

- ReactNative is the name of the folder.
- InventorsArena is the name of the project.

`

Answer (score -1):

I deleted the node modules and re-installed it. Now it is working.